# "EntityNotFoundException: Unable to load RELATIONSHIP with id" when saving RelationshipEntity (with huge generated cypher query)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am using spring-data-neo4j 4.2.0.M1 and neo4j-ogm 2.0.4 with neo4j 3.1.0-M04.

The application is generally working, except for one case where I try to save a collection of modified RelationshipEntities.
The code is sth. like this:

```
List<Relationship> updatedRelationships = new ArrayList<>();
for(Relationship relationship : modifiedRelationships)
{
  relationship = relationshipRepository.load(relationship);
  relationship.setValue("value");
  updatedRelationships.add(relationship);
}
relationshipRepository.save(relationships);
```

The RelationshipEntity is annotated with @RelationshipEntity and has a few properties in addition to the @StartNode and @EndNode. Only the property mentioned above is changed though. The RelationshipEntity is `load`ed inside the loop because I previously noticed lost information (namely value of other properties) when executing this.
Note that the above mentioned code is executes for many RelationshipEntities in succession. Each relationship (probably) occurs only once, but start and end nodes probably occur several times. To my knowledge, no relationship is deleted though.

The exception I get is:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to load RELATIONSHIP with id 20683203.
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.DiskLayer.relationshipVisit(DiskLayer.java:432)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.CacheLayer.relationshipVisit(CacheLayer.java:326)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StateHandlingStatementOperations.relationshipVisit(StateHandlingStatementOperations.java:1409)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.relationshipVisit(ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.java:416)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.relationshipVisit(OperationsFacade.java:493)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.getRelationshipById(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:300)
... 104 common frames omitted
```

The query that is executed before (which is probably the "save" query) is huge and exceed the character limit here (sth. like 200k characters). Apparently the query touches where more relationships than necessary (from business logic point-of-view) since only about 30 entities are actually saved. I would assume that the resulting query (or queries if updates are done per entity) are rather brief.

```
2016-08-28 20:16:33,007 I [pool-4-thread-1               ] (EmbeddedRequest.java:155)     Request: START r=rel({relIds}) FOREACH (row in filter(row in {rows} where row.relId = id(r)) | SET r += row.props) RETURN ID(r) as ref, ID(r) as id, {type} as type with params {relIds=[13744338, 19099951, 12570789, 12570785, 13744377, 13648126, 12570765, 20627727, 13744356, 20627724, 12570760, 19263773, 19257628, 20113678, 19099932, 19259756, 18796874, 13783174, 19097972, 19083644, 19099970, 19097921, 19077446, 19263810, 13744312, 20568405, 20904270, 19097937, 12570827, 20627779, 20648258, 12570816, 20683195, 19259812, 20683194, 20683193, 20683192, 19083690, 20683186, 20683191, 19259819, 18819471, 20683178, 20683177, 12570669, 20683176, 19276210, 19933607, 20683171, 18844038, 19100089, 20683174, 20683173, 20683163, 20683162, 20683161, 13744242, 19257729, 12570649, 20683165, 20683164, 19087754, 21703141, 12570641, 8341711, 19259796, 8704051, 19915155, 19261851, 13783062, 13783063, 19091955, 18182597, 19276276, 19276275, 20623852, 20607468, 20623853, 19100155, 19233277, 13783048, 19261946, 12570719, 21789101, 12570718, 19075526, 19259842, 19257807, 12570707, 13715516, 19098061, 19261908, 20683208, 20683215, 19100118, 20683212, 20683203, 19276254, 20683201, 20683207, 19091934, 20683206, 19261915, 19097639, 19101736, 19101749, 18821129, 19097659, 19124284, 13662709, 13744628, 19052549, 19089427, 13744612, 19265563, 19251300, 19089509, 19251298, 20631665, 19251305, 19265642, 13744513, 19261558, 19261511, 19265606, 19081291, 18903113, 18903114, 19251273, 8341775, 12597685, 13744548, 19081308, 18725021, 18725020, 19273892, 19099808, 19089572, 19097772, 13744449, 13683011, 18178177, 19273905, 19093694, 18178231, 19124358, 20633756, 13744502, 19081356, 18651311, 19093661, 20562171, 19263725, 20625639, 19099901, 20631774, 20676819, 18651383, 20676822, 20676821, 20676820, 19097811, 19099862, 13744428, 20631751, 18178280, 18668312, 19100453, 19088171, 20708148, 19143487, 19088184, 19094334, 18668349, 13744883, 19145485, 20607750, 19094301, 19086108, 13744792, 20611958, 19143528, 13662849, 13744829, 12571346, 20611918, 20611919, 18811753, 19100506, 13744813, 19084195, 13662806, 20708275, 19098546, 20612001, 13744752, 20708253, 12595823, 20611976, 19147673, 19258343, 19274725, 19084262, 19082212, 19096548, 20591606, 19086317, 13662720, 8348332, 19274738, 8348329, 19096571, 21703569, 19440630, 13744654, 21824427, 13744701, 19258320, 20612032, 19086296, 19080158, 19282466, 19145249, 19261996, 20607539, 12596170, 19282472, 18776588, 19100208, 12596183, 18182658, 19233341, 19278395, 19096126, 19098115, 20640284, 18844217, 19255810, 19259919, 19257864, 20623892, 19091980, 19933697, 19282450, 19100180, 19261981, 12596219, 12596113, 19255924, 20707949, 12596118, 19098228, 18704970, 12596122, 19278458, 19096190, 19278456, 19253826, 19278412, 13745087, 19100241, 13745066, 18704995, 19278500, 13744981, 5954519, 19094199, 19143356, 13744970, 12598116, 18840242, 13745006, 18676445, 18008789, 19096298, 18676426, 20607724, 13744906, 13755199, 19094227, 12596419, 19098918, 19256621, 19090736, 21075287, 19100929, 21851496, 20876568, 13681912, 12596463, 12596465, 19090704, 10951825, 12596471, 13681897, 13753581, 19094814, 12596352, 21703948, 21695756, 18699605, 19256693, 18818378, 12596376, 19090755, 19256647, 13681844, 19082583, 18836839, 18699621, 12596409, 20618681, 21544395, 19916202, 12596299, 12596310, 19436940, 19099014, 19094918, 19916170, 13681782, 12596335, 20680073, 13681762, 13681763, 19099028, 19094938, 21081473, 13681682, 20680177, 12596242, 19099126, 19500540, 21081496, 10492993, 19099087, 21081517, 19099094, 21704112, 19098665, 18680849, 12596685, 12596689, 19274804, 20648995, 19137597, 21048411, 19088387, 19262470, 20657183, 19086357, 19258397, 18680869, 12596731, 19088413, 19272807, 19274848, 19272811, 12596622, 18811984, 15797667, 19096694, 19082357, 19262579, 19274875, 19137604, 12596642, 19274830, 19098696, 13682107, 12596651, 19096655, 20632650, 19088474, 19274845, 19262555, 19100834, 13682007, 19098794, 19100851, 12596565, 20556972, 19254450, 20597926, 12598622, 20597925, 20649114, 19100800, 13682036, 19100806, 12596582, 18703539, 20638856, 20598010, 18703582, 19094763, 19100905, 19096808, 20634857, 20597991, 5877179, 5877178, 20597977, 5877181, 19098822, 12596527, 12596532, 19199781, 19265313, 19261228, 20625200, 19257134, 20625201, 18714376, 19085108, 19253054, 19253048, 19265339, 20637459, 20637456, 19085074, 21081974, 8316482, 20598534, 18714402, 19107685, 19253090, 20615029, 19097462, 19263346, 20621152, 19263352, 19259207, 13729470, 19085140, 20688830, 19251116, 19259304, 13678173, 20615087, 12596830, 19097474, 21082087, 12596840, 19263368, 19251093, 8701488, 19267475, 8349384, 12572165, 8349360, 12596751, 19077119, 12596765, 20625380, 19077057, 19089350, 21825447, 21702567, 13682208, 12596785, 8316559, 18178020, 19253207, 20688847, 12596788, 19267536, 20688838, 12570558, 19232295, 12570550, 13783001, 20643352, 20694547, 19095051, 20643338, 19232272, 12570505, 20641280, 20694529, 20641284, 19099164, 20821624, 20821626, 20631165, 20821619, 12570606, 19439229, 12570601, 18820674, 19232327, 12570588, 20694621, 20641362, 20119134, 20631115, 20680264, 20618831, 19093080, 18824862, 19256994, 7325670, 20821668, 19257017, 13782863, 16494427, 20620952, 19256967, 20637331, 18030271, 8267731, 19256977, 20670095, 19099360, 20637433, 19261170, 19265276, 20907749, 18822910, 20621021, 19099339, 19252938, 19936961, 19099345, 19109599, 19257048], rows=[omitted]
```

I've tried to load the relationship with that id directly, but none exists. The same code executes fine for other RelationshipEntities but repeatedly fails for either this or one of a handful other ones.
Any ideas as to what could cause this or how this can be better debugged?

Comment: Could something other than this application be deleting relationships?

Comment: I doubt it. The application runs an embedded neo4j database and no other process inside the application should be active at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I *somehow* solved this with the following steps:

- Replaced saving the RelationshipEntity with saving the modified NodeEntity
- Making such modifying operations sequential (previously this could happen in parallel)
- Encapsulate the modifying operation in a transaction
- Fixed a bug where in the same transaction the same entity was saved twice (without changing again in the meantime)
- Fetching the entity again at the beginning of the transaction in order to have the latest state available

Since I was prettty much in the dark about this topic until it finally worked, I am not sure if all of the steps actually helped solving this. It may actually have been only a subset.
What I can see though now is, that the huge update queries are now smaller (albeit still quite big) but actually seem to contain "real" updates instead of mostly "null" properties. I assume that previously it didn't really contain an update and was instead overriding properties with "null". The fact that this is now working is probably related to the fact, that the entity is now updated before beginning to modify it and that no other modifying operation can run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me it was simply the neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver 
version I had to include in my pom. The one I defined overwrote the one 
defined in spring-data-neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

If you only save the relationshipEntity,you could only using next snippet:

```
List<Relationship> updatedRelationships = new ArrayList<>();
for(Relationship relationship : modifiedRelationships)
{
  relationship = relationshipRepository.load(relationship);
  relationship.setValue("value");
  updatedRelationships.add(relationship);
}
relationshipRepository.save(updatedRelationships,0);
```

it would save the related properties on `relationshipEntity` and meanwhile ignore any related entities.